# Cooking own Machine Learning Dataset

Tags: dataset, prepared-statement

How do I prepare/cook dataset on my own for healthcare?
Building a Disease prediction engine for which I need to prepare a dataset.

Comment: What is your dataset compose of, images, text, numbers? ??

Comment: You can take some ideas from other health related datasets ( lung cancer , diabetes prediction ) on kaggle.com

Comment: One such example for malaria detection is here -> “Detecting Malaria-Infected Cells With Machine Learning and TensorFlow” https://medium.com/predict/detecting-malaria-infected-cells-with-machine-learning-and-tensorflow-4f17ac491662

Comment: I have significant attributes as protein, carbohydrates, fat,zinc in daily food intakeetc and target as disease/disorder